# jenkins osx node wrong environment variable

Tags: windows, bash, macos, shell, jenkins

I setup my jenkins on Windows 7 machine, to run xcode build, I add a Mac slave node to it, however, the node inherits Windows environment variable and can't find any of the mac command (even the simplest like `sh` or `git`)

I set PATH in the node config, as well as EnvInject

```
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.

[project] $ /bin/bash /var/folders/r8/29j5d4f15csc0x727z1y6zr8000086/T/hudson5065016463950292533.sh

path = C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;...all_windows_path_here
```

this causes all this wierd command not found errors:
`/var/folders/r8/29j5d4f15csc0x727z1y6zr8000086/T/hudson5065016463950292533.sh: line 5: which: command not found
/var/folders/r8/29j5d4f15csc0x727z1y6zr8000086/T/hudson5065016463950292533.sh: line 6: which: command not found
/var/folders/r8/29j5d4f15csc0x727z1y6zr8000086/T/hudson5065016463950292533.sh: line 7: which: command not found
/var/folders/r8/29j5d4f15csc0x727z1y6zr8000086/T/hudson5065016463950292533.sh: line 8: whoami: command not found
/var/folders/r8/29j5d4f15csc0x727z1y6zr8000086/T/hudson5065016463950292533.sh: line 9: whoami: command not found
whoami = 
./setup-git-svn-repo.sh: line 3: dirname: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the slave should not inherit the environment from the master unless the method you use to start the slave agent explicitly does that.

It looks like your slave agent is not being started correctly; you can review the directions for starting a unix like agent (osx) from windows: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Differentwaysofstartingslaveagents

Comment: I have tried all the 4 methods, none seems to work.. the best one is the ssh method but it gives that path problems